# Automatic view positioning JEditorPane

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jeditorpane

Is there  way to automatically change the view position of `JEditorPane` to its highlighted text content?

Answer (score 2):

```
editorPane.scrollRectToVisible( editorPane.modelToView(...) );
```

Comment: thanks i tried your suggestion. This is my code: `RPSearchToolView.jEditorPane1.scrollRectToVisible(RPSearchToolView.jEditorPane1‌​.modelToView(RPSearchToolView.jEditorPane1.getSelectionEnd()));` But it wont work. Is there something wrong in my code?